# How can I delete multiple data in specific index in elasticsearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I need to delete the multiple record in specified index/type. i follow this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917327/delete-all-documents-from-index-type-without-deleting-type)  stil i have same issue

I need to delete all documents in gvisitor type in g_visitor index, i follow below command

```
curl -XDELETE http://10.1.2.10:9200/g_visitor/gvisitor
```

its throw below error

```
No handler found for uri [/g_visitor/gvisitor] and method [DELETE]
```

Then follow to install **Delete By Query** plugin and try to remove documents 
,

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://10.1.2.10:9200/g_visitor/gvisitor/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed' -d '{
    "query" : { 
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}'
```

Its throw below error:

```
  {
     "found":false,
     "_index":"g_visitor",
     "_type":"gvisitor",
     "_id":"_delete_by_query",
     "_version":1,
     "_shards":{
        "total":2,
        "successful":1,
        "failed":0
     }
  }
```

Suggeset me, How can i delete multiple or all documents in specific type of index in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete a mapping type, hence why your first query doesn't work.

You can only delete an index

```
curl -XDELETE http://10.1.2.10:9200/g_visitor
```

If you want to use the delete-by-query approach, you can do so, but you need to [install the plugin first](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html)

```
sudo bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```

Then you can use the plugin like this by calling the `_query` endpoint (not `_delete_by_query`!!):

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://10.1.2.10:9200/g_visitor/gvisitor/_query?conflicts=proceed' -d '{
    "query" : { 
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}'
```

Comment: i already installed `delete-by-query ` plugin and try deleted above mentioned way its not works for me

Answer (score 0):

if you are using delete-by-query you need to use terms instead of match_all

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://10.1.2.10:9200/g_visitor/gvisitor/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed' -d '{
    "query" : { 
        "terms" : {}
    }
}'
```