# Attempting to delete all the data for an Index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to delete all the documents, i.e. data from an index. I am using v6.6 along with the dev tools in Kibana.

In the past, I have done this operation successfully but now it is saying 'not found'

```
{
  "_index" : "new-index",
  "_type" : "doc",
  "_id" : "_query",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "not_found",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 313,
  "_primary_term" : 7
}
```

Here is my kibana statement

```
DELETE /new-index/doc/_query
   {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
```

Also, the index GET operation which verified the index has data and exists:

```
GET new-index/doc/_search
```

I verified the type is doc but I can post the whole mapping, if needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all documents from index/type without deleting type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917327/delete-all-documents-from-index-type-without-deleting-type)

Answer (score 2):

Easier way is to navigate in `Kibana` to `Management`->`Elasticsearch index mapping` then select indexes you would like to delete via checkboxes, and click on `Manage index` -> `delete index` or `flush index` depending on your need.

[image]

Comment: thanks Kamil - I was foxed by the fact they moved this from "Index Patterns"

Answer (score 2):

Only solutions currently are to either delete the index itself (faster), or delete-by-query (slower)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/docs-delete-by-query.html

```
POST new-index/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Delete API only removes a single document https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/docs-delete.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by using a delete by query:

```
POST new-index/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Delete documents is a problematic way to clear data](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/free-disk-space-monitoring-after-deleting-records/146651/2).

Preferable delete index:

```
DELETE [your-index]
```

From kibana console.

And recreate from scratch.

And more preferable way is to make a [template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/indices-templates.html) for an index that creates index as well with the first indexed document.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that someone changed a field's name and now the DB (NoSQL) and Elasticsearch string name for that field doesn't match. So Elasticsearch tried to delete that field, but the field was "not found".

It's not an error I would lose sleep over.